# How to Draw Line in Android by Dragging

Tags: android

I am creating a coaching board. I aim to draw a line between two points. Initial position is in the image below:
[image]

If I drag the chip away from the initial position, it should draw a line. When I move the chip, it should always draw a line.

This is what I tried:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Toast.makeText(this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            int startx = 50;
            int starty = 100;
            int endx = 150;
            int endy = 210;
            canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);
            break;
```

I put that code inside the ontouchlistener of the chip.
You can download the project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggfbsbkaokj9vxi/CoachingBoard.rar?dl=0

Comment: What a straight line? from the `ACTION_DOWN` point to the `ACTION_UP` point?

Comment: About the toast: Do you know about `Log` class and the logcat?

Comment: @weston Yes a straight line. I know the Log class and I'm very much aware of the Logcat. But it is easier to see in a toast if it executes a certain block of code rather than scrolling down thru the logcat list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further examining your code, I believe I have achieved what you'd like.

We're going to go to `DrawingView` and define a getter for `drawCanvas`, so we can access our canvas outside of the `DrawingView` class.

Next we're going to head to `Basketball` and do the following:

```
float startX;
float startY;
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = event.getRawX();
            startY = event.getRawY();
            ...
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Paint paint = new Paint(); //set this as a field in drawView with another getter to avoid garbage collection penalties
            paint.setStrokeWidth(15f);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            drawView.getCanvas().drawLine(startX, startY, event.getRawX(), event.getRawY(), paint);
            drawView.invalidate();
            break;
    }
}
```

What this does: when you pick up the chip it will save the starting coordinates, and when you drop the chip it will draw a line in your `drawView` canvas from start to end.

You can even draw the lines as a continuous `Path` so the lines always touch, but that is outside the context of this answer.

Comment: Thanks! It works well. But why does the lines are gone after moving other chips?

Comment: @JaysonTamayo, I have no idea, I cannot replicate that in my environment. Lines are not erased. If you feel I've helped you, consider clicking the check mark on the left :-)

Comment: The lines are not erased in your side?

Comment: No, the lines stay regardless or which or how many chips I move.

Comment: Can you send me your project file please? :) Maybe I've done something wrong.

Comment: I've only changed what I showed you. I tested it on an emulator running api v21 maybe that made a difference?

Comment: I will try to download and apply your changes to the original code and I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you so much MeetTitan. You don't know how much you helped me. :)

Comment: Another quick question, what if I want that as I move the chip, a path is also drawn?

Comment: @Jayson, You'd want to update the line on "ACTION_MOVE" and make it permanent on " ACTION_UP"

Comment: I moved the code in the ACTION_UP to the ACTION_MOVE but the paths are not drawn.

Comment: Look at your code in `DrawingView` for a guideline to go off of. Except you'd be drawing a line based on start and stop.

Comment: I got an idea from `DrawingView`. But it's drawing the lines in the top right of the screen. See the picture here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4fuhrgsnbdd3jh/Screenshot_2015-03-02-14-08-59.png?dl=0

Comment: Your coordinates must be wrong. Try `event.getRawX()` and `event.getRawY()`. Post a new question if you can't get it.

Comment: Thanks it is now working. I used `event.getRawX()` and `event.getRawY()`.

Comment: @Jayson, please look into the difference between `event.getX()` and `event.getRawX()` to understand why one worked when the other would not.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution to draw a line by dragging is to get x and y positions from ACTION_DOWN and then get ever next x and y position from ACTION_MOVE, outside the switch statement, invalidate the canvas. draw the line with this starting x,y and ending x,y positions.

Code of these all explanation is below:

```
public class TouchEventView extends View {
float downxpos;
float downypos;
float upxpos;
float upypos;
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path()
public TouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);       
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(downxpos, downypos, upxpos, upypos, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downxpos = event.getX();
            downypos = event.getY();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            upxpos = event.getX();
            upypos = event.getY();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

hope this will help you and other community if you need more description feel free to ask.