# I tried all I thought that should be work, why does the drawLine is not following my touch coordinates? It's not accurate

Tags: java, android, coordinates, touch-event

*Refer to the video below, here's my current code :*

Inside of **Oncreate** method :

```
       rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativemain);
```

And this method is where I put the Gif images to act as the chips, I also need help into this one because when I add the **addRule** to change the location of the chip, It turns out that I can no longer drag it:

```
private void mvb_chip(ImageView view, int a) {
    view = rootLayout.findViewById(a);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new mvb_direct.ChoiceTouchListener());

}
```

And Lastly here Is the touch listener to drag the chips! Inside of the ACTION.UP is where I drag the chips and put a drawline (credits to this guys  answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28489989/19026761, and my problem is why the drawLine is not exactly similar to my touch X and Y, see the video below.

```
float startX;
float startY;
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();


        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;

                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();



                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setDither(true);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

                drawbleView.getCanvas().drawLine(startX,startY,event.getRawX(),event.getRawY(),paint);
                drawbleView.invalidate();
                break;



            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250
```

[image]

Comment: It works but It can no longer create a vertical line after I drag up and down, It shows diagonal

Comment: yes, after using getX() and getY(), It became accurate, but It is only drawing a line from the first recorded ACTION DOWN. every time I touch the screen, a line from the first x and y is showing even the location of chip is in the middle.

Comment: It can draw a line after dragging the imageview vertically, but now It only drawing a line diagonally.

Comment: look at the video, that's the initial result. However after changing it to getRaw(), It became accurate yet It can only spawn horizontal and diagonal line

Comment: Even though I change that drawbleView.getCanvas().drawLine(startX,startY,event.getRawX(),event.getRawY(),paint); to getX() and getY(), the result become more problematic, the Line is small and hiding in the first location of the views.

Comment: Yeah, hang on, I misunderstood your code; thought the listener was on the parent. Lemme think about what would be the simplest fix.

Comment: OK, if `drawbleView` is the chip's parent, or lines up exactly with its parent, then I _think_ we might be able to do simply `startX = event.getX() + view.getX();`, and similarly in the other three spots.

Comment: FWIW, I did a quick mock-up from what I can gather of your setup, and that does work, even with the margin adjustments: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJyFY.png. (Sorry, can't do video on this machine.) Just make sure to change the `drawLine()` values, too.

Comment: Sorry, late reply, IT IS WORKING NOW after putting, startX = event.getX() + view.getX(); in the drawLine() too. Thanksssss.

Comment: How can I undo the line by the way? :'(

Comment: Generally, when you want to be able to undo things like that, you keep track of each line draw so that you can recreate the whole image just without the "undone" one. For example, make a simple class like `class LinePoints { float x1, y1, x2, y2; }`, and keep an `ArrayList<LinePoints>` that you can iterate over to redraw everything if needed. Make sense?

Comment: that's actually amazing, you are godsend